# How to access ImageUrl property of the Image Control placed inside a ItemTemplate in the GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

My GridView Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdVw" visible="False" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataFi

eld="Comment" HeaderText="Comment" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Review Document">
                <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:Image ID="currentDocFile" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="reviewDoc_UpldFl" runat="server" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My Bind Method that I call from Page_Load and after Cancelling/Updating, etc:

```
    private void BindGrdVw()
    {
        List<ArticleComments> commentsList = ArticleCommentsBLL.GetComments(ArticleID);
        if (cruiseReviewsList.Count != 0)
        {
            GrdVw.DataSource = commentsList;
            GrdVw.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "ID" };
            GrdVw.DataBind();
            GrdVw.Visible = true;
        }
     }
```

..Now as you see I have a template field, I access the 'FileUpload' control in the EditTemplate by 'FindControl()' of the row that I'm editing. but how can I access the 'Image' control's property 'ImageUrl'.

I need to set it to something like the following, this is a sample code from another project in the code behind file but I was able to access the image directly.

```
currentProfilePic_Img.ImageUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cruisesPpUploadPath"].ToString() + currentCruise.ProfilePic;
```

*The AppSettings returns the path for the folder that I use for uploading.

*currentCruise is an object and it's properties was assigned through my DAL layer.

Comment: _When_ do you want to assign it? Directly after data binding?

Comment: I thought I'd assign it in my BindGrdVw() or assign it from the MarkUp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do...

If you want to bind the image control URL dynamically, you will have to hook into the RowDataBound event of the GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdVw" visible="False" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GrdVwDataBound">

protected virtual void GrdVwDataBound(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var imageControl = e.Row.FindControl("currentDocFile") as Image;
        imageControl.ImageUrl = // Image URL here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound.aspx

Comment: but this solution will force me to implement my Bind() method here! .. and I want to have a sepearate Bind() Method so I could call it on only specific events, Like the first time the page loads, Updating, Adding, Deleting.

Comment: This method will be called whenever row data is bound. I'm not sure why you would need to call it on the specific events you mentioned as it will be getting called in these scenarios already?

Comment: Of course I know that and this a problem, because my each time the page reloads it will be a trip to my database .. right ?

Comment: Not necessarily, you should only be binding your GridView if the page load event is NOT a postback. Otherwise yes, you have to assume it's a fresh visitor the page and re-bind. If you want to minimise your trips to the DB, you could cache the items being bound to the GridView then refresh the cache at an interval you set

Comment: btw I went with using the Bind method in the mark up it was better because when If I implemented this I don't think I'd be able to see the data from the source. so it worked with the Bind in the mark up. but thanks this is a perfectly healthy answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the Image right from the start:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GrdVw.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(GrdVw_RowDataBound);
}

void GrdVw_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Image rowImage = (Image) e.Row.FindControl("currentDocFile");
        rowImage.ImageUrl = whatever;
    }
}
```